# Add Time to MYSQL Data Using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the below SQL to extract the time from MYSQL column

```
SELECT CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(dt_tracker, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%i:%s '),
        DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(dt_tracker, INTERVAL 2 HOUR), '%H:%i:%s'),
        DATE_FORMAT(dt_tracker, ' %p')) AS dt_tracker2, 
        imei, speed 
FROM gs_objects 
WHERE imei = '862203228005404'
```

It shows me the database time with the two hours added when I echo the result as below

`echo "<td align='left' >" . $row['dt_tracker2'] . "</td>";`

Problem I have it shows the original time and the time adding the two hours. I just want to see the new time not the Database time

**08:41:24 10:41:24 AM**

So the 08:41:24 I do not want to show on the page I would rather have the date there which is also in the same column as the time as shown below

**2023-04-14 08:42:48**

I am not sure how to remove the MYSQL DB time and add the date

Comment: Just let mySQL return the date part `SELECT DATE('2023-04-14 08:42:48')`

Comment: The date is correct but the time 08:42:48 is two hours behind thus I need to add 2 Hours to the time from the DB. But when I echo it it shows the Original time and the time adding the two hours

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to show the date and then the time where you've added 2 hours? If so, why not just do: `DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(dt_tracker, INTERVAL 2 HOUR), '%Y/%m/%d %H:%i:%s %p')`? There's no need for any concatenation. It will also make the date change if the original time was less than two hours from midnight.

Comment: @M.Eriksson I have used your suggestion and it works. Great thanks was under impressions CONCAT was required to assist with format but it didn't help me much. Thank you

Comment: Yes, I meant `DATE(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(dt_tracker, INTERVAL 2 HOUR), '%H:%i:%s'))`. You can use functions to wrap functions :)